# Problema validación pegada en combo box y bloqueo de botones de ventana modal

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentado validar un estado que se muestra en un combo box en una ventana modal.La validación funciona correctamente esta bloquea unos botones dependiendo del estado que muestre el combo box, pero el único inconveniente es que si por ejemplo:

Hay 4 validaciones de pendiendo del estado.
existen 4 estados

```
PENDIENTE
POR CONFIRMAR
CANCELADA
CONFIRMADA

Si selecciono estado PENDIENTE , se debe bloquear el botón enviar
Si selecciono estado POR CONFIRMAR , no se debe bloquear nada.
Si selecciono estado CANCELADA , se debe bloquear botón guardar, botón enviar y combo box estado
Si selecciono estado CONFIRMADA , se debe bloquear boton guardar, boton enviar y combo box estado
```

las validaciones funcionan correctamente, pero existe un problema.

Al validar cualquier estado, por ejemplo si se selecciona el estado "CONFIRMADA" Se bloquean los botones "Guardar" y "Enviar" y ademas se bloquea el combo box "estado" , 
pero si cierro el modal y selecciono otro registro y abro el modal, este me sigue mostrando los botones bloqueados y el combo que se bloquearon anteriormente 
y debería mostrar los botones y el combo según el estado del registro que se esta seleccionando para ver.

Imagenes

1.-Listado de registros cada uno con su estado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

2.-Se edita un registro y se despliega el modal con los datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.-Se cambia de estado a CONFIRMADA, por lo tanto se bloquan los botones y el combo box.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.-Se cierra modal visualizandose nuevamente la pantalla con el listado de los registros.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

5.-Se edita otro registro que tiene otro estado y debería bloquear los botones y combo según la validación correspondiente.Pero se sigue mostrando todo bloqueado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema básicamente es que se queda pegada la validación en si , ya que los demás datos del modal se actualizan correctamente, y solo si recargo la pagina y selecciono otro registro ahí me muestra los botones y el combo box bloqueado o desbloqueado según la validación.

Intenté desapareciendo los botones y el combo don .hide() y al abrir el modal mostrando nuevamente con .show() pero no funciona correctamente ya que sigue mostrando  la validación pegada.

como se puede hacer?

Acá dejo el código jquery de la validación.

```
<script>

$("#txt_mostrar_estado").change(function() {



if( $("#txt_mostrar_estado").val()==="PENDIENTE"){
    $( "#btnEnviarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $( "#btnGuardarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", false );
}
if( $("#txt_mostrar_estado").val()==="POR CONFIRMAR"){
    $( "#btnEnviarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", false );
    $( "#btnGuardarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", false );
}
if( $("#txt_mostrar_estado").val()==="CONFIRMADA"){
    $( "#btnEnviarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $( "#btnGuardarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $("#txt_mostrar_estado").prop( "disabled", true );
}
if( $("#txt_mostrar_estado").val()==="CANCELADA"){
    $( "#btnEnviarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", true );
    $( "#btnGuardarReserva" ).prop( "disabled", false );
}




});

$("#txt_mostrar_estado").trigger("change");

</script>
```

Acá el código del modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDetalleReserva" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">



<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

<div class="modal-content modal-lg">



<div class="modal-header btn-info">
<h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel" style="color:white">


<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">

</span> 

Detalle Reserva

</h3>


<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">


<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>


</button>



</div>



<div class="modal-body modal-lg">


    <form method="POST">

        <b>Asignar Vuelo</b><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAsignarVuelo" style="font-size:19px"></button>

    </form>
         <hr>    

             <form method="POST" action="modificarReservaClienteServlet.do">
                 <table class="table-condensed table-hover" id="tablaDetalleVuelo">

                     <thead class="input-sm">
                         <tr>

                             <th>Nº RESERVA</th>
                             <td><input type="text"  id="txt_mostrar_num" class="form-control" name="txt_numero_reserva_cliente" readonly="readonly"></td>
                         </tr>
                          <tr>
                             <th>ORIGEN</th>
                             <td><input type="text"  id="txt_mostrar_origen" class="form-control"  name="txt_origen_reserva_cliente"></td>


                             <th>DESTINO</th>
                             <td><input type="text"  id="txt_mostrar_destino" class="form-control"  name="txt_destino_reserva_cliente"></td>


                             <th>ORIGEN VUELO</th>
                             <td><input type="text"  id="txt_mostrar_origen_vuelo" class="form-control" name="txt_origen_vuelo_reserva_cliente"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <th>PIEZAS</th>
                             <td><input type="number"  id="txt_mostrar_piezas" class="form-control"  name="txt_total_piezas_reserva_cliente"></td>


                             <th>PESO</th>
                             <td><input type="number"  id="txt_mostrar_kilos" class="form-control"  name="txt_total_kilos_reserva_cliente" step="any"></td>


                             <th>VOLUMEN</th>
                             <td><input type="number"  id="txt_mostrar_volumen" class="form-control"  name="txt_total_volumen_reserva_cliente" step="any"></td>
                         </tr>
                         <tr>
                             <th>ESTADO</th>
                             <td>

                                 <br>

                                 <select class="form-control" name="combo_estado"  id="txt_mostrar_estado" onchange="activarBoton()" required >


                                    <option value="PENDIENTE">PENDIENTE</option>
                                    <option value="POR CONFIRMAR">POR CONFIRMAR</option>
                                    <option value="CANCELADA">CANCELADA</option>
                                    <option value="CONFIRMADA">CONFIRMADA</option>
                                 </select>
                             </td>
                             <th>PRIORIDAD</th>
                             <td>

                                 <select class="form-control" name="combo_prioridad_reserva_cliente" id="txt_mostrar_prioridad"  required="Prioridad" >
                                    <option>ALTA</option>
                                    <option>MEDIA</option>
                                    <option>BAJA</option>
                                 </select>

                             </td>
                         </tr>


                         <tr>
                             <th>FECHA CREACIÓN</th>
                             <td><input type="date"  id="txt_mostrar_fecha_generacion" class="form-control"  name="txt_fecha_creacion_reserva_cliente" readonly="readonly"></td>


                             <th>FECHA EMBARQUE</th>
                             <td><input type="date"  id="txt_mostrar_fecha_embarque" class="form-control"  name="txt_fecha_embarque_reserva_cliente"></td>


                             <th>TIPO RESERVA</th>
                             <td>

                                 <select class="form-control" name="combo_tipo_reserva_cliente" id="txt_mostrar_tipo_reserva"  required="Tipo de Reserva" >
                                    <option>COMPLETA</option>
                                    <option>PARCIAL</option>
                                 </select>

                             </td>

                         </tr>
                         <tr>

                         </tr>

                         <tr>
                             <th>FORMA DE PAGO</th>
                             <td>

                                 <select class="form-control" name="combo_forma_pago_reserva_cliente" id="txt_mostrar_forma_pago"  required>
                                    <option>EFECTIVO</option>
                                    <option>TRANSFERENCIA</option>
                                 </select>
                             </td>



                             <th>TARIFA</th>
                             <td><input type="number"  id="txt_mostrar_tarifa" class="form-control"  name="txt_tarifa_reserva_cliente" step="any"></td>



                             <th>MONEDA</th>
                             <td>

                                 <select class="form-control" name="combo_tipo_moneda_reserva_cliente" id="txt_mostrar_tipo_moneda"  required>
                                    <option>CLP</option>
                                    <option>USD</option>
                                 </select>
                             </td>
                         </tr>


                     </thead>

                      <tbody class="input-sm">    
                      </tbody>
                 </table>
                 <hr>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" id="txt_mostrar_notas" name="txt_notas_reserva_cliente"></textarea>


                 <br><br>
                 <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGuardarReserva" onclick="modificarReserva()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" ></span> Guardar</button>
                 <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" id="btnEnviarReserva"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk" id="enviar"></span> Enviar</button>
                 <button type="button"  class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="cerrar"></span> Cerrar</button>
             </form>
         <hr>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onclick="mostrarRutaReservasPorAjax()">Ver Tramos</button>
         <div id="resultadoRutaReserva"></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Aquí el codigo del servlet que muestra el listado de registros en la pagina principal.

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    ReservasDao mostrarReservaClienteDao=new ReservasDao();
    //GuiasDao gdaoDisp=new GuiasDao();
    Usuario usuarioCliente=new Usuario();
    try
    {
        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        usuarioCliente.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUser")));
        ResultSet resultadoReservas=mostrarReservaClienteDao.verReservasCliente(usuarioCliente);

        ArrayList<Reserva>reservasCliente=new ArrayList<Reserva>();

        if(request.getParameter("idUser").isEmpty())
        {
            String errorVerReservasCliente="No se ingresó datos de entrada";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorVerReservasCliente", errorVerReservasCliente);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("errorVerReservasCliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {

            while(resultadoReservas.next())
            {
                //reservasCliente.add(new Reserva(resultadoReservas.getInt("COD_SEQ_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("EST_RVAS")));
                reservasCliente.add(new Reserva(resultadoReservas.getInt("COD_SEQ_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_VLO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("EST_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("NOTAS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("FECH_GEN_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("FECH_EMB_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("PRIO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_TFA_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TARIFA_CNT_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_MONEDA_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("RUT_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("NOMB_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("TEL_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("DIR_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("EMAIL_CLIENTE")));
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("reservasCliente", reservasCliente);
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("airExpressClientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table class='table-condensed table-hover table-responsive' id='resultado'>");
            out.println("<thead class='input-sm'>");
            out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>N° Reserva</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Origen</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Destino</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Origen Vuelo</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Piezas</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Kilos</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Volumen</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Estado</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Notas</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Fecha Creación</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Fecha Embarque</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Tipo</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Prioridad</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Forma Pago</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Tarifa</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Tipo Moneda</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Rut Cliente</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Nombre Cliente</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'style='display:none'>Telefono Cliente</th>");
                out.println(" <th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Direccion Cliente</th>");
                out.println(" <th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Email Cliente</th>");
                out.println(" <th class='btn-info'>Acción</th>");

            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println(" </thead>");
            out.println("<tbody class='input-sm'>");


                      try
                      {

                      for(int i=0; i<reservasCliente.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            out.println("<tr>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getDestinoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalPiezasReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalKilosReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalVolumenReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getEstadoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNotaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getFechaCreacionReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getFechaEmbarqueReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getPrioridadReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoMonedaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getRutCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNombreCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTelefonoCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getDireccionCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getEmailCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"
                                                    + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    //+ " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAsignarVuelo' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalReservaClienteEliminarReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + "</td>"); 
                                        } 

                      }
                      catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
                      {
                          ex.getMessage();
                          out.print("</tr>");
                      }

            out.println("</tbody>");
            out.println("</table>");


out.println("<script>\n" +
"      $(document).ready(function () {\n" +
"          $(\"#resultado tbody tr\").on (\"click\",function (event) {\n" +

"              //var value = $(this).val();\n" +

"              var id= $(this).find(\"td:first-child\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_num\").val(id);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id2= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(2)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_origen\").val(id2);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id3= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(3)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_destino\").val(id3);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id4= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(4)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_origen_vuelo\").val(id4);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id5= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(5)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_piezas\").val(id5);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id6= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(6)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_kilos\").val(id6);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id7= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(7)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_volumen\").val(id7);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id8= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(8)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_estado\").val(id8);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id9= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(9)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_notas\").val(id9);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id10= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(10)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_fecha_generacion\").val(id10);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id11= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(11)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_fecha_embarque\").val(id11);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id12= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(12)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_tipo_reserva\").val(id12);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id13= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(13)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_prioridad\").val(id13);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id14= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(14)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_forma_pago\").val(id14);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id15= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(15)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_tarifa\").val(id15);\n" +

"              \n" +

"              var id16= $(this).find(\"td:nth-child(16)\").html();\n" +

"              $(\"#txt_mostrar_tipo_moneda\").val(id16);\n" +

"              \n" +

"          });\n" +

"      });\n" +

"\n" +

    "</script> ");

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        }

    }
    catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException nullex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VerReservasClienteServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, nullex);
    }



}
```

en el servlet , en la tabla html que muestra el listado de registros hay un botón que abre el modal

```
<button type='button' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>
```

y el codigo jquery que tiene el servlet es el que enviar los valores de la tabla html al modal.

Será problema de cookies o es un problema de la validación?
por favor me podrían ayudar?

Comment: En donde asignas los valores del modal?

Comment: hola, ahora agregue el código. es un servlet de java el que muestra el listado de registros en una tabla html y en esa tabla hay un botón que despliega el modal y los valores que recibe el modal los recibe por una función de jquery que tiene el  servlet que básicamente captura los valores de la tabla y los envía al modal.

Comment: hola que podría ser el problema?

Comment: Intenta agregar `$("#txt_mostrar_estado").trigger("change");` despued de que asignas el valor en el servlet.

Comment: A tu dices agregar $("#txt_mostrar_estado").trigger("change"); al final de la función de jquery que tengo en el servlet?

Comment: Asi es mi estimado

Comment: hola no funciona en el servlet, sigue el mismo problema.